# Not possible to solve for maximum with differentiation? Now what?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have some function $f(x)$ which I want to maximise

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}x^{1-\rho}}}{e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}x^{1-\rho}}+e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}b^{1-\rho}}}$$
Where $0<\rho<1$ and $b,x>0$

$f(x)$ has no global maximum value, but
I know that $f(x)$ is maximised (subject to a constraint) when $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=c$ where $c$ is some positive constant. So we have

$$argmax_{x\in{R}}(f(x)) \iff\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}x^{1-\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho-1}b^{1-\rho}}}{x^{\rho}\big(e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}x^{1-\rho}}+e^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}b^{1-\rho}}\big)^2}=c$$

This does not allow me to solve for $x$ (it's simply intractable). However, I can graph the derivative and see where it equates to $c$ (see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4rbeou0gsj)). Hence, it seems like a maximum should exist, but I simply cannot express it. Is there a way to overcome this problem? Are there other methods for optimizing subject to constraints without differentiation?

Comment: You have a function of one variable.  There are numeric algorithms to find a local maximum.  I would start by plotting it over the range of interest.  Any numerical analysis text will have one or more algorithms for this.  I like the discussion in chapter 10 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html)

Comment: This doesn't even appear to need basic calculus, so what am I missing? Letting $f(x)=\frac{1}{\rho-1}x^{1-\rho}$ and dividing numerator and denominator by $e^{f(x)}$ gives $\frac{1}{1 \; + \; \exp[f(b)-f(x)]},$ which is maximized when $\exp[f(b)-f(x)]$ is minimized, or when $f(b)-f(x)$ is minimized, or when $f(x)$ is maximized. However, $f(x)$ has no maximum for $x > 0,$ since $f(x) < 0$ for all $x>0$ and $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}.$

Comment: You forgot about the constraint, which results in a maximum iff the first derivative is equal to some constant $c$.

Comment: I didn't forget about the constraint, but instead I didn't know what you meant. Maybe your first sentence should be rewritten? Perhaps you mean something like the following? (I'm just guessing at this point.) "Let $f(x) = \ldots,$ where $\ldots$ It is easy to see that $f(x)$ has no global maximum value, because $\ldots$ [maybe say something similar to what I previously said] However, if we additionally require $\ldots$ [state exactly what constraint you want to impose], then $\ldots$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got $$f'(x)=-{\frac {{x}^{1-\rho}}{x}{{\rm e}^{{\frac {{b}^{1-\rho}}{\rho-1}}}}{
{\rm e}^{{\frac {{x}^{1-\rho}}{\rho-1}}}} \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {{x}
^{1-\rho}}{\rho-1}}}}+{{\rm e}^{{\frac {{b}^{1-\rho}}{\rho-1}}}}
 \right) ^{-2}}
$$ and for this first derivative we get $$f'(x)<0$$

Comment: Hmm. I got something else, I believe.

For instance insert the following equation

e^((1/(1-p))*x^(1-p))/(e^((1/(1-p))*x^(1-p))+e^((1/(1-p))*b^(1-p)))

here, https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

Comment: Or input (e^((1/(1-p))*x^(1-p)))/((e^((1/(1-p))*x^(1-p)))+(e^((1/(1-p))*b^(1-p)))) on http://www.wolframalpha.com/